# How to calculate forecasts with a SARFIMA Model?

Tags: time-series, arima, arfima

I want to fit a multiplicative seasonal ARFIMA model of the form $(1 - \phi_1 L - \phi_2 L^2 - \ldots - \phi_p L^p) \times (1 - L)^d \times (1 - L^6) \times X_t = \varepsilon_t
$ and perform forecasts. $L$ is the lag parameter, $d$ is the differencing order (non-integer), $p$ is the order of the AR part. Unfortunately, there is no package that I can use, so I tried the following:

Firstly, I calculated the weights for fractional difference: $\left(1-L\right)^{d}X_{t}=X_{t}-dLX_{t}+\frac{d\left(d-1\right)}{2!}L^{2}X_{t}-\frac{d\left(d-1\right)\left(d-2\right)}{3!}L^{3}X_{t}+\cdots=\varepsilon_{t}$  and obtained a "new" time series. Then I fitted the "new" time series to the rest of the model (AR part and seasonality) with a package while setting d=0. I optimized for d with the best model fit. Now, I got all the coefficients $\phi$. However, how can I do forecasts or compare the fitted model to the actual data (in-sample comparison)? Using the fitted model, I would neglect the fractional difference part. Does someone have a suggestion to proceed? Or how to do this task differently?